# travis ci yml build ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework, travis-ci

I am new to Travis CI.

I created a `.travis.yml` file in my project. You can see it [here](https://github.com/BurnsedFoundation/Tipsy/blob/master/.travis.yml).

So when I committed this file, I saw that there were three separate node.js builds that were kicked off in travis-ci.org.

Is there a starter `.travis.yml` to build a ionic iOS app? 
I have not been able to find anything on the web.

Comment: I don't understand.  Are you having issues with how travis-ci builds your app?  Are you looking for boilerplate iconic code?  What issue are you running into?

Comment: I am really just looking for a good tutorial on how to build an ionic iOS app using travis CI.

Comment: did u find solution in meanwhile?

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Travis you should read the docs, or at least their guides on getting started

The Travis CI docs have a [guide](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/objective-c/) on building an Objective-C Project. Which lets you specify Xcode version and so on.
This is not enough to build an ionic iOS app though and you should add the stages needed to go through which are specified at the [Ionic docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/testing.html).

There is also a comprehensive [guide](https://www.objc.io/issues/6-build-tools/travis-ci/) by Mattes Groeger on setting up Travis CI to build an iOS project